# Put a condition on del keyboard for multiinput

Tags: sapui5

I have a multi input and to remove tokens you can either delete them with the X button or with the del keyboard, I want to put conditions where the user can't delete all tokens for example or there must be at least one token ( it is done with the X button but with del keyboard I can delete all tokens and that's not what i want ), I want to put condition on key board del

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar by changing the function of the input "onChange" and checking if the last "del" empties the field. If it does, I just set to the last existing value (saved previously in a global var). That's all :)

Regards